# Technical report table of contents

Tags: tables, margins

- I am writing a technical report. Pease how do I replicate something this nature using report class.
- Could someone please assist with the page layout (boxed margins, a simple table in header)

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,headheight=2cm,headsep=4ex]{geometry}


\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[inner sep=0pt,text width=\linewidth+2ex+\pgflinewidth,anchor=center] (H) at (current page header area.south) {%
   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{a} & b                  & c                  & d                  & e \\ \cline{2-5} 
                   & \multirow{3}{*}{i} & \multirow{3}{*}{j} & \multirow{3}{*}{k} & f \\ \cline{5-5} 
                   &                    &                    &                    & g \\ \cline{5-5} 
                   &                    &                    &                    & h \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
   };
   \draw ([shift={(-1ex,-1ex)}]current page text area.south west) rectangle
          (H.north east);
 \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\newpage



\include{Section_8}
\end{document}
```

Current output:

[image]

Comment: Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable example showing what you have tried.

Comment: Provided is a minimal code and output

Comment: This isn't really a table of contents, since it shows the number of pages rather than the page number directly.  OTOH, the information needed is stored in the aux and toc files, but accessing those files can be tricky.  Frankly, the easiest solution is to fill out a tabular by hand.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! I am a bit lost, you posted an image you want to match with sections only and then posted your solutions with sections and subsections... Please post your actual/final table of content and elaborate on what you want to change so that it would match your desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tabularx` we can get the desired header in a `fancyhdr`, and we can draw the page border and lower right rotated text with `tikz`. The table of contents would be done by hand as @John Kormylo said in the comments to the question. All together you can get a similar result with:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm,top=4cm,headheight=2cm,headsep=4ex]{geometry}

% Add page frame and bottom left box in margin area
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \draw (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
   \node[draw, rotate=90, anchor=south west] at (current page text area.south west) {some text};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Add tabular header and the footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|X|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{FICHTNER} Consulting Engineers ( India ) Private Limited}\\\hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{a} & b                  & c                  & d                  & e \\ \cline{2-5} 
    & \multirow{3}{*}{i} & \multirow{3}{*}{j} & \multirow{3}{*}{k} & f \\ \cline{5-5} 
    &                    &                    &                    & g \\ \cline{5-5} 
    &                    &                    &                    & h \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
}
\lfoot{a}
\cfoot{b}
\rfoot{c}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{center}
HEADER
\end{center}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{INDEX}\\
Section&Description&No. of Sheets\\
a&b&c\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]